# Accessing CDI SessionScoped bean doesn't work in Java 8 parallel stream

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, java-8, cdi

I'm having trouble understanding why this code doesn't work. Basically I want to access a CDI SessionScoped bean from a CDI ViewScoped bean during a parallelStream() function, I get this exception:

```
WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
```

This is running in Wildfly 10.1.

**The ViewScoped bean:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@ViewScoped
@Named
public class TestController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject SessionController sessionController;

    public void works() {
        List<Function<String, String>> functions = new ArrayList<>();
        functions.add((String input) -> {
            return sessionController.getSomething();
        });
        functions.add((String input) -> {
            return sessionController.getSomethingElse();
        });
        functions.stream().forEach(f -> f.apply("input"));
    }

    public void doesNotWork() {
        List<Function<String, String>> functions = new ArrayList<>();
        functions.add((String input) -> {
            return sessionController.getSomething();
        });
        functions.add((String input) -> {
            return sessionController.getSomethingElse();
        });
        functions.parallelStream().forEach(f -> f.apply("input"));
    }
}
```

**The SessionScoped bean:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String getSomething() {
        return "something";
    }
    public String getSomethingElse() {
        return "else";
    }
}
```

**The XHTML:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head />

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Works" action="#{testController.works}" />
            <br />
            <p:commandButton value="Does Not Work" action="#{testController.doesNotWork}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:689)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at com.SessionController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getSomething(Unknown Source)
    at com.TestController.lambda$3(TestController.java:33)
    at com.TestController.lambda$5(TestController.java:38)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

We have theories that the session may be thread specific, but no hard proof.

Also curious if there's a work-around. The real code is much more complex than this so we can't preload the SessionController results beforehand without losing the benefits of the parallel stream.

Comment: I still haven't seen a real world case where parellel streams are critical for performance reasons

Comment: In this case I'm firing off a different SQL query in each function, so I only have to wait for the longest one to complete against our SQL Server.

Comment: Parallel streams are not meant to be used in IO operations. Instead, they are intended to be used to perform parallel calculations, such as summing the elements of a very long list by partitioning the list into N parts and performing the sum of the N partial lists in parallel, and finally summing the subresults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think you are bumping into is that using parallel streams means you will run in multiple threads. Now, that is a problem with CDI and contexts, because you would need context propagation - e.g. in the main thread you currently have (for instance) session context active, but when you create another thread, it is not active there.

[Chapter 6.3 in spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#normal_scope) describes it more in-depth but to give you the short story - **context propagation to other threads does not work by default**. And there are good reasons for that - it would be very costly (synchronization) and you would need to solve loads of very weird situations such as having one of the threads invalidation session, hence de-activating session context while other threads operate on it. And many more such situations.

Also, there is no built-in workaround for this. What you could do though, is implementing your own scope, or enhancing existing session scope, but that would be very complicated I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the scopes were so closely tied to the threads. Appreciate your time and effort into this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parallelize queries in Java EE, I suggest that you use ManagedExecutorService for that. Fork join pool, which parallel streams use, is meant for parallelizing computations, not IO.

When it comes to CDI context propagation, you may find BoundSessionContext useful, assuming you are using WELD as your CDI implementation. Read more at http://john-ament.blogspot.fi/2014/01/bridging-netty-resteasy-and-weld.html

Probably you can manage without a bound session context. Just gather all necessary data from session context and pass it to the worker threads.